# Google SQL instance stuck after operation "restore from backup"

Tags: google-cloud-sql

After I proceed to restore database from automated backup file generated on Mar 13, 2019, the SQL instance stuck in this state forever:"
Restoring from backup. This may take a few minutes. While this operation is running, you may continue to view information about the instance."
The database size is very small, less than 1MB.

Comment: Google Cloud Support here! To investigate the issue, there are more information needed, that are private and can not be posted here.  If you have a Google Cloud support, please fill a support ticket. If you do not have support, please open [a private Google issue](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) using your project ID. Than post the link to issue that you created as a comment here. With this link I can take a look into your project.

Comment: As a workaround you can try to [restore backup on a new Cloud SQL Instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/restoring#restorebackups-another-instance)

Comment: @PawelCzuczwara The SQL instance is backup running now. Thanks. It took longer time than usual and showed An unknown error occurred. But the instance works now and recovered itself.

Answer (score 1):

For future users that experience problems like this is in the future, here is how you can handle it:

If you have a Google Cloud support package, file a support ticket directly with support for the quickest response.

Otherwise please file a [private GCP issue](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) describing the problem, remembering to include the project id and instance name.

However - Cloud SQL instances are monitored for stuck states like this, so often the issue will resolve itself within a few hours.